# Can you get computers with Ubuntu preloaded in the UK?

Tags: hardware

I found some places which sell computers in the US that have Ubuntu preloaded but not in the UK. Can you buy computers with Ubuntu preloaded in the UK? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DELL sells Ubuntu preloaded computers in UK also. Check this url:

http://www.dell.co.uk/ubuntu

To ensure the availability in other countries, you may check this url:

http://www.ubuntu.com/dell

If you could't find your country in the list on above url it doesn't mean that Ubuntu preloaded systems are not available in your country. For example I bought my lap from India and obviously it is preloaded with Ubuntu.

Comment: Dell is [no longer selling Ubuntu PCs online](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/dell/7910090/Dell-drops-Ubuntu-PCs.html), but they may be available if you phone them.

Answer (score 7):

[Linux Emporium](http://www.linuxemporium.co.uk/) is one of the oldest linux hardware suppliers I think.

Dell probably sells a netbook with Ubuntu too (but you might have to look on their "business site" to find it).

And I'm sure there are also several small shops that will sell you computers with Ubuntu on request.

Answer (score 5):

Here is all the places the company ZaReason ships to: http://zareason.com/shop/International.html

They sell Linux OS on hardware and gear. I have never tried one of their machines however I have only heard positive things through reputation.

Comment: As of February 2012, ZaReason are no longer shipping to the UK.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look on Amazon.co.uk for computers and laptops with Ubuntu pre installed.

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Eco-145-Desktop-Computer-Processor-Integrated/dp/B007LJVI0O/ref=sr_1_14?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1348390034&sr=1-14

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Zoostorm-Ubuntu-Laptop-Pentium-Processor/dp/B008HKA0Z0/ref=sr_1_6?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1348390034&sr=1-6

Also check out uMi computers website is www.umipc.com for preinstalled computers and laptops.

Answer (score 0):

What abou DELL? Don't they retail in UK or did they discontinue Linux preloaded already?
ASUS EEEPC netbooks also come with a Linux installer last time I heard but not sure if it was Ubuntu they were using.

Comment: The question was regarding computers preloaded with **Ubuntu**. These computers are not loaded with Ubuntu.

Comment: Of course DELL sells *Ubuntu* preloaded in many countries, maybe not yet in the UK. That exactly was the message of Marky's answer. IMO no reason for down-voting.

Comment: The Eee PC comes preinstalled with Xandros linux. Also, I have neither upvoted you nor downvoted you.

Comment: Oh yes - the Xandros issue. This is a highly customized Debian based Linux adapted for eeePC by Asus. Asus-Xandros is not supported by Xandros Inc..